Angular 16 ag-grid-community how to set cellEditorParams dynamically
I am trying to set cellEditorParams dropdown option values dynamically based on the current row data. The dropdown menu should have certain values depending upon the values in other columns.
I found an example on how to do something similar in this example code but I wasn't able to get it working.
ATTEMPT 1:
When attempting to pass the data object as a parameter to values, the handleGridCellEvent works, but values array.forEach is not recognized as function.
ERROR "TypeError: params.values.forEach is not a function"
const columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  {
    headerName: 'Example',
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      // ERROR "TypeError: params.values.forEach is not a function"
      values: (data) => this.getCellEditorValues(data),
      // Handle grid cell event works
      handleGridCellEvent: this.onCellChange.bind(this),
    },
    
  },
] as ColDef[];
this.tableOptions = { columnDefs, pagination: false }

ATTEMPT 2:
When attempting to pass the data object as a parameter to cellEditorParams, the values are populated dynamically, but the handleGridCellEvent is not recognized as a function.
ERROR "TypeError: colDef.cellEditorParams.handleGridCellEvent is not a function"
const columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  {
    headerName: 'Example',
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: ({ data }) => {
      return {
        // Values works
        values: this.getCellEditorValues(data),
        // ERROR "TypeError: colDef.cellEditorParams.handleGridCellEvent is not a function"
        handleGridCellEvent: this.onCellChange.bind(this),
      }
    },
    
  },
] as ColDef[];
this.tableOptions = { columnDefs, pagination: false }

Other methods for reference:
private getCellEditorValues(data: any): string[] {
  // Return an array of cell editor values dynamically based on data
  return ['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3']
}

private async onCellChange(data: any) {
  // Process request on cell change
  this.exampleService.processRequest(data);
}

